# Populate the columns of one table with the records of another

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have one table, `FRUIT`, describing some measurements that I make:

```
ID Tag Amount   Units   
1  A     75    Apples     
2  B     23   Bananas
```

I would like another table, `HISTORY`, that tracks the amount of fruit over time, much like a historian. That is every x seconds/minutes I would like to record the current amount of fruit at that time.

```
Time      A    B
earlier   35   45
Now Now   35   23
Now       75   23
```

The trick is that if the `FRUIT` table is updated to include say Carrots one simply adds a record. How then would one add a field to `HISTORY` to account for this?

My understanding is that the user has to specify the information for `FRUIT` i.e. when adding a record to `FRUIT`, this is simply an extra record. For `HISTORY` however I'm now adding an extra field. Is it possible to do this on the fly? I know before hand that every column other then time is of type numeric/double/float and I can fully specify the other properties for the field using similarly known information. I'm just not sure how to do this automatically.

If it helps any I'm in MSAccess for now but will switch to MySQL soonish.

Comment: So if you reach to have a thousand fruits, you intend to have a table with a thousand columns? And then what, when you have a million fruits?

Comment: Mostly I want a configurable historian. One would specify the properties in one table and automatically include the column for recording in the second. It's my understanding that databases are best for this.